# onMouseOver on <tr> doesn't cover cell with backgorund-image

Tags: html, css, hover

I would like that the `onMouseOver` effect row be applied on  the whole row.

**CSS:**

```
tr:hover{       
    background-color: #FFEEC2;
    border-width: 1px 1px 1px 1px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #4B4B6F;
    cursor: default;
}
```

**HTML :**

```
<table>
    <tr onClick="javascript: printit();">
        <td class="MenuImage"><img src="/images/print.gif" width="16" height="16"></td>
        <td class="MenuCaption">Print</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

But the hover effect only works in the cell with the Print label. How can I make the hover effect work on the cell with the `print.gif` image as well?

Comment: can u create a fiddle of it so we can check it and test it?

Comment: @Dead Man WHat is a fiddle?

Comment: Look here: jsfiddle.net

Comment: @BillyMoat means [this](http://jsfiddle.net/nescalante/v4QHQ/). You may have an image that is occuping the whole cell

Comment: Your function printit should be in header HTML part

Answer (score 0):

To build on Dead Man's fiddle and lante's point, this demo shows what you might be seeing. The hover state works, but the image hides the effect.

http://jsfiddle.net/v4QHQ/12/

One solution might be to apply padding around your images:

http://jsfiddle.net/v4QHQ/13/

```
td {
    padding: 10px;
}
```

Comment: actually, someone come with a right  solution that suited me. But the answer , which suggested putting background-image: none; in the :hover was cancelled.

Comment: Ok. Feel free to answer your own question or close it.

Answer (score 0):

Someone came up with an answer who worked perfectly.

The answer suggested putting background-image: none;

```
     tr:hover{       
       background-color: #FFEEC2;
       border-width: 1px 1px 1px 1px;
       border-style: solid;
       border-color: #4B4B6F;
       cursor: default;
       background-image: none;
    }
```